# Silverlight 5: Toolkit Chart, Setting Axis interval from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, charts

I have a multiple line series toolkit chart. The X axis it has is of type DateTimeAxis.

The value binded to this X axis can change according to StartDate and EndDate of selection. 
Example a certain Product XYZ has StartDate = Jan 1, 2012 and EndDate = Dec 31, 2012. 
simillarly another product may have this range too huge.

So I decided to set the interval for this axis in code behind. But that does not seems to work. Any help/pointers please.

XAML Axis:

Here i set interval in code: (here numdays is number of days difference ie. Range (between start and end date)

```
 if (numDays > 0 && numDays <= 55)
                {

                    DelX.Interval = 1;

                }
                else if (numDays > 55 && numDays <= 111)
                {                      
                    DelX.Interval = 2;}
```

Comment: forgot to mention the XAML Axis:

 <toolkit:DateTimeAxis Name="DelX" AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource DateFormat}"  ShowGridLines="True" Orientation="X" Location="Bottom" IntervalType="Weeks">
                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                </toolkit:DateTimeAxis>

Comment: Where exactly do you set the interval? It will not work in a constructor, you should wait until axes are loaded. Also I suppose you should set `DelX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days` as well